# Как сделать скриншот окна UAC?

Tags: windows, uac

Как сделать скриншот окна UAC?
Или окно защищенное и заскриншотить никак нельзя?

Comment: У меня не работает, стоит самый строгий режим.

Comment: @Zergatul можно таким способом, как в ответе сделать скриншот, даже при самом строгом режиме (скрин проверки добавил). Может поможет в будущем, очень полезная функция :)

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046940/how-to-screen-shot-a-uac-prompt

Answer (score 4):

Вы не написали какая ОС (7,8,10?).
К примеру приведу вариант, как это можно провернуть:

В ОС [Windows 10 начиная с версии 1703](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/capturing-screen-contents-the-prntscrn-key-win/df0f73fb-286f-4588-aace-357fe3b5422a), появилась функция захвата экрана.
Для того, чтоб захватить выбранную область нажмите последовательно комбинацию клавиш: <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, после этого выделяете необходимую область и просто отпускаете левую кнопку мыши.
Скрин для проверки (проверенно на Windows 10 Pro; Version 1809; OS Build: 17763.316):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Принципы работы контроля учетных записей](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/security/user-account-control/how-user-account-control-works)

Comment: благодарю, полезный ответ. Буду иногда пользоваться, до этого использовал Yandex скриншот, ну и другие внешние программы

Comment: @Alexandr_TT я и сам не так давно узнал, что у Windows есть такая функция, теперь взял за правило, после каждого большого обновления системы, читаю что Microsoft добавило.

Comment: В режиме защищённого окна (UAC) не работает, но спасибо.

Comment: @TomaszKaczmarek можно всё-таки уточнить в какой ОС, так как есть отличия.

Answer (score 4):

Windows с максимальным уровнем защиты UAC переключает систему на защищенный рабочий стол Winlogon перед тем, как вывести окно UAC. Можно отключить защищенный рабочий стол:

- С помощью редактора групповых политик: **secpol.msc** -> **Локальные политики** -> **Параметры безопасности** -> отключить **Контроль учетных записей: Переключаться на безопасный рабочий стол при запросе повышения** (**User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation**)
- Через реестр: Установить в ключе  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System** значение **PromptOnSecureDesktop** равным 0.

Тогда окно UAC будет запускаться как обычно, и его скриншот можно сделать обычным Print Screen.

---

Однако, остается вопрос: а что, если хочется сделать скриншот именно защищенного рабочего стола? Как оказалось, это можно сделать. Для этого понадобится:

1. Программа, умеющая сохранять скриншоты в файл по нажатию горячей клавиши (например [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org)).
2. Утилита [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) из пакета PsTools.

Для создания скриншотов защищенного рабочего стола необходимо запустить нашу скриншотную программу от имени локальной системы на рабочем столе `WinSta0\Winlogon`. Командная строка для запуска выглядит так:

```
PsExec /h /x /d /s "C:\Program Files\Greenshot\Greenshot.exe"
```

(запускать, само собой, из командной строки, запущенной с правами администратора)

После этого, когда появилось окно UAC, нажимаем горячую клавишу (Ctrl+PrintScreen в случае GreenShot), и готово: на защищенном рабочем столе появляется диалоговое окно, позволяющее сохранить изображение в файл!

[image: dialog]

Результат:

[image: screen]

На самом деле, все проходит не совсем гладко: GreenShot сыплет кучей сообщений об ошибках, будучи запущенным в защищенном рабочем столе, но главное, что это работает, скриншоты сохраняются.

Источники:

[Guided Help: Turn off the secure desktop in Windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/975788/guided-help-turn-off-the-secure-desktop-in-windows-7)

[How to take a screenshot of Window's secure desktop?](https://superuser.com/a/758754/1001787) - ответ участника [Antonio Dias](https://superuser.com/users/283926/antonio-dias)

Comment: Благодарю за пошаговый способ и в общем за перевод! +1

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Благодарю за отличный ответ и за то что напомнил о `Mark Russinovich`  замечательном разработчике и о его сайте `sysinternals` которого сейчас нет, так как его купила в 2006 году windows А какие там были шикарные программы  типа -`AutoRuns`

Comment: Добавляю ссылку [AutoRuns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)  Очень полезная утилита. Можно отследить, включить, выключить процессы, сервисы, драйвера, кодеки причем это не удаляется при снятии галочки. Всегда можно включить обратно.

Answer (score -1):

Я это сделал за 5 сек и не меняя настройки винды. С соседнего компа захожу на исследуемый по RDP ( любой доступный отображатель рабочего стола). через этот RDP запускаю что мне надо, в момент выдачи окошка с сообщением с удаленного компа делаю ptr scr , ножницы и все что угодно. Если экран заблокирован, то надо перейти в оконный интерфейс. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]